# Basic R, how to populate a vector with results from a function

Tags: r, vector, convex-hull

So I have a list of coordinates that I perform a chull on.

```
X <- matrix(stats::rnorm(100), ncol = 2)
hpts <- chull(X)
```

chull would return something like "[1] 1 3 44 16 43  9 31 41".  I want to then multiple X by another vector to return only the values of X that are in the result set of chull.   So for example [-2.1582511,-2.1761699,-0.5796294]*[1,0,1,...] = [-2.1582511,0,-0.5796294...] would be the result.  I just don't know how to populate the second vector correctly.

```
Y <- matrix(0, ncol = 1,nrow=50)   #create a vector with nothing
# how do I fill vector y with a 1 or 0 based on the results from chull what do I do next?
X[,1] * Y  
X[,2] * Y
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only the values of `X` that are in the result set of `hpts`, use

```
> X[hpts]
## [1]  2.1186262  0.5038656 -0.4360200 -0.8511972 -2.6542077 -0.3451074  1.0771153
## [8]  2.2306497
```

I read it like "X such that hpts", or  "the values of hpts that are in X"

Of course, these values of X are different from yours, due to my values of `rnorm`

To get a vector of 1s and 0s signifying results use

```
> Y <- ifelse(X[,1] %in% X[hpts], 1, 0)
> Y
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
## [44] 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: I need a result that's 50 in size.  X[hpts] is only 8 in size right?

Comment: What if there aren't 50 values?  Use "NA", or zero, etc?

Comment: Zero,  I want another vector with just [1,0,1...] with a 0 being if that row number is not in the results of chull.  It dosn't have to be a 1 though, if you can put the actual value here easily, that will save a few steps.

Comment: Okay, I updated it.  It shows where the `hpts` are in X.  If you want to add a column, we'll need a bit more work.

Comment: Great, I made Y <- ifelse(X[,1] %in% X[hpts],1,0)
and now X*Y appears to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Great!  I updated my answer once more to exactly match what you want.