# R retain order from a vector, apply it to another vector

Tags: r, vector, convex-hull

This is related to a previous question:

[Basic R, how to populate a vector with results from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22072194/basic-r-how-to-populate-a-vector-with-results-from-a-function)

But I thought I would post a new one because I have an additional requirement.  Take this R code.

```
X <- matrix(stats::rnorm(100), ncol = 2)
hpts <- chull(X)
Y <- ifelse(X[,1] %in% X[hpts], 1, 0)
c(X,Y)
Z <- matrix(0,ncol = 1,nrow =50)
```

I want to add in an additional vector Z preserving the order of hpts.  So if t(t(hpts)) looks like this:

```
[1,]   48
[2,]   27
[3,]   15
[4,]   13
[5,]   39
[6,]    2
[7,]    5
[8,]   50
```

then I want the 48th row Z to have 1, the 27th row to have 2, the 15th row to have 3 etc.etc.  I have attempted to do this with a for loop::  for (i in Y) {...} but I have not had success.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Z[c(hpts),1] <- seq_along(hpts)
```

Comment: @KrisErickson, it's called a replacement.  See the documentation for `[` for more details.  Basically, you can index the portion of a vector/matrix you want to replace, and then fit in a vector of (typically) the same size there.